# Time zone not recognized on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, timezone

I am working on a Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit virtual server hosted at GoDaddy.

Whenever I change the time zone to Amman (UTC +2:00), and wait around 1 minute, a message appears in the clock fly-away indicating that the timezone is not recognized. And the time gets reset to its original value before changing the time zone.

Message: Your current time zone is not recognized. Please select a valid time zone using the link below.

Screen shot: http://i53.tinypic.com/10n7zh5.jpg

I tried restarting the machine after changing the time zone but the message did not go away.

I tried other time zones (e.g. Pacific Time UTC-8:00) and the same thing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you changing it as an Administrator and is the machine in a domain?

Comment: Yes, I am using an Administrator account and the machine is not joined to a domain.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a the answer from godaddy's support forum here:
http://community.godaddy.com/groups/go-daddy-customers/forum/topic/in-my-vps-windows-in-godaddy-i-cant-change-timezone/

All the VPSs automatically synchronize their time with the parent server. Changing the timezone is not allowed on the VPS level.

Comment: It's Microsoft who don't have a better idea other than resetting time zone every time virtual machine boots.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a XenServer hosted virtual server, then try this:

- Enable the following Citrix Policy:
      **Citrix Presentation Server Console** -> **User Workspace** -> **Time Zones** -> **Do not use Client’s local time**
- And manually set a proper Time Zone via the Change date and time settings… GUI

[Source](http://forums.citrix.com/message.jspa?messageID=1533775#1486654)

Comment: I don't think it is hosted on XenServer because I don't see the Citrix Console anywhere.